# TeXstudio - Can the editor and the pdf viewer be arranged vertically?

Tags: texstudio

In TeXstudio 2.12.14, the embedded pdf viewer is displayed to the right of the editor. Is there a setting that allows the pdf viewer to be displayed either at the bottom or top of the editor?

Comment: you cant do that with the embedded viewer, just use the windowed viewer then you can arrange it however you like. there's a duplicate qn of this somewhere...

Comment: @Troy It's doable with the windowed viewer but then two windows are created. I was looking to keep both the editor and the embedded viewer in a single window as it happens when they're side by side. Thanks!

Comment: nope, not possible at this time, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The editor part of TeXstudio can be split horizontal or vertical see [texstudio split screen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472478/texstudio-split-screen/472480#472480)

The viewer Section can not but you can as you know have one imbedded window and any number of floating viewer windows including an external one. Using Windows split screen and snapping makes these fairly easy to position and there were many 3rd  party apps to control how screen division can be locked into profiles for multiple apps. but most of these were abandoned as windows 10 screen features improved.

[image]

For other ways to run dual compile using split editor and viewers see
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473233/170109 (dual sessions/instances)
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472480/170109 (split editor) and
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471069/170109 (split viewers)

Comment: I was going for having the editor at the bottom and the embedded viewer at the top. Now I'm using a tiling manager so I'm using the windowed viewer and rearranging the both the editor and viewer windows. I thought it'd just be easier if it'd be done inside a single window.

Comment: I know @Troy initially answered similar to above and "nope" not currently possible. Your tiling manager solution is certainly the best work-around unless someone can convince the developers its essential to you and others work-flow, however unless we all get switched by some manufacturer ploy to exceptionally tall and narrow tablet screens its unlikely there will be many others with a pressing need.

Comment: Just out of interest which tile manager do you find works for you ?

Comment: The only I've used and still using is [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/) in Manjaro XFCE. If you want to get some ideas, check out [/r/unixporn](https://old.reddit.com/r/unixporn/).

Answer (score -2):

In TeXStudio, the viewer windows is incorporated to the program window, but can be individualized and even, given to an application like Sumatra. I ignore if the new arrangement can be permanent, but TeXStudio can remember its window configuration, which could aleviate its repeated use.

Comment: For those that gave me a negative valoration, I recommend that test what I said. The pdf viewer, can be separated from the program or configured to use Sumatra. That way you can arrange your windows as you wish.